# UITableview with UIPageControl?

Tags: iphone, sdk

I am in the making of a restaurant "step by step" ordering app, where I want to list the menu (appetizers, main course etc) in a tableview with the ability to organize the menu contents with a UIPagecontrol. Something similar to the eat24 app way of doing it or how the weather forecast app is constructed.

[image]

[image]

I already have the tableview set up, now I just need to implement this, which I hope you will help me with or guide me in the right direction, for me to accomplish this :). Would I need to setup a tableview for each of the categories or would it be possible to just update one tableview with the needed information, by swiping to the left or use arrows in a toolbar in the picture? What would the best way to add a toolbar like the one picture (white ring), using the storyboard -> resize tableview and drag the image in or to set it up programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1** - *Updating your tableView*
You may update your `dataSource` so it reflects the state of the "new" tableView. Than you call `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` by using `UITableViewRowAnimationRight` or `UITableViewRowAnimationLeft`, depending of whats fitting at the moment. This will feel like scrolling to a new tableView. For swiping you could use a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`.

**Option 2** - *Using a scrollView with multiple tableViews*
If you want it a little bit easier just setup three tableViews and throw them in a `UIScrollView` with paging enabled.

**PageControl**
Of course you need to add and setup a [UIPageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html), if you want to show those dots.

**Regarding the UI:**
You can setup everything in your Storyboard. The background, the arrow buttons, the `UIPageControl`, you can even add the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` within the Storyboard.

Comment: Hi Jaydee3, thank you for your usefull answer. I just have one more question. Which method would be best, seen from a memory usage point of view?

Comment: Option 1, because it needs only a single tableView.