# UItableViews in a ScrollView or UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am making an iOS app and I need to show some kind of a horizontal scroll view with some table views in it. It must look this way:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53942814/Pic1.png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53942814/Pic2.png

When user swipes left or right the corresponding table view is to be displayed.

I found two ways to do it:

1. a UIScrollView with UITableViews
2. a UICollectionView.

Does anyone have in idea what is the best way and how to implement it?

Comment: Use UIPageControl for this scenario .

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableview with UIPageControl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312119/uitableview-with-uipagecontrol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented exact same in my code which replicates android like control…

Please see some part of my code you will get some ideas

I have done it by adding Views to UIScrollView.
Used 2 scrollviews one for title and one for tables

**1. Adding table views to scrollview for table**

pageNo = 1;

```
for (Page *page in pageArray)
{
    UIStoryboard *mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    PageContentViewController *contentViewController = [mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pageContentViewController"];

    contentViewController.detailsDictionary = page.deviceDetailDictionary; //assigning dictionary will use as table data source

    /* Content page's x position calculation */

    // Formula: xPos = scrollViewWidth * ( pageNo -1 )
    // Where,
    // pageNo starts with 1

    int xPos = self.detailScrollView.frame.size.width * (pageNo -1);
    contentViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 0, self.detailScrollView.frame.size.width, contentViewController.view.frame.size.height);
    pageNo ++;

    [self addChildViewController:contentViewController];
    [self.detailScrollView addSubview:contentViewController.view];
    [contentViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

**2. Add UILabels to titleScrollView**

Just check this formula to add title UILabel views to top scroll view

```
    // Formula: xPos = 75 + 10 * pageNo + (pageNo -1) * 150;
    // Where,
    // pageNo starts with 1
    // 75 = Left margin of first title
    // 10 = Space between two labels
    // 150 = Width of label
```

**3. Use Delegate method of ScrollView (in which you added table) to handle swipes**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.detailScrollView.frame.size.width;

    //1. Calculate page no. if 50 percent or more area of any page visible make it as current page
    int pageNo = floor((self.detailScrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 2;

    //2. Make only current page (calculated in 1.) visible by scrolling to that page in detailScrollView
    //Formula : xPos = pageWidth * (pageNo -1)
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake( pageWidth * (pageNo -1), 0, pageWidth, 50);
    [self.detailScrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];//OR set content offset

    //3. Make title visible of current page by scrolling to that title in titleScrollView
    //Formula : xPos = (pageWidth / 2) * (pageNo -1)
    CGRect titleFrame = CGRectMake( 160 * (pageNo -1), 0, pageWidth, 10);
    [self.titleScrollView scrollRectToVisible:titleFrame animated:YES];//OR set content offset

    //Fade effect for non current titles

    //Set all page title alpha to low value
    for (UILabel *title in pageTitleArray)
    {
        [title setAlpha:0.5];
    }

    //set current page alpha to 1
    UILabel *title = [pageTitleArray objectAtIndex:pageNo -1];
    [title setAlpha:1];
}
```

Code in 3 takes care of moving to next / prev page on swipe with animation

Hope this will be good starting point for you...

Comment: I've found one thing about this method. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53942814/Pic2.png There is some space pasted in the scroll view before the table view. And I spent some hours trying to determine where it comes from. And finally found the reason. I use the navigation controller to navigate through views in my app. And this space is equal to the space of the navigation controller bar. And when I delete the navigation controller, everything becomes fine. But I really need nav. controller. How to deal with this problem?

Comment: Didn't get anything by attached png. See this demo project https://github.com/AdityaDeshmane/iOSCustomPageControllerDemoProject this is how i am using it.